# Passive dative voice if it is correct

Tags: passive-voice

Can I say "I was bought a car" meaning that a car was bought for me or it is incorrect. And the following sentence "The universe expands" it means that The Universe expands something or The universe itself is being expanded ? I was bought or I was given sometimes is used but it seems a bit ambiguous to me it seems like I was bought or given from someone to someone like slavery .

Comment: *I was bought* is an ***intransitive*** passive verb usage, where the implied subject *(**somebody** bought me)* is unspecified. Unless you actually were a slave, that would probably be some kind of metaphor and/or exaggeration. That same interpretation could in principle apply to *I was given* - somebody gave me (to someone else). There wouldn't be many contexts where you might say ***I was bought a car***, because usually it would be more natural to mention ***who*** bought you the car. But syntactically, it's fine, ***if that's what you're asking*** (I'm not clear on that point).

Comment: Thanks for explanation. What about the second example with the " The Universe expands" what it means "The Universe expands something or The universe itself is being expanded ? The Universe does the action or the action is applied to the universe. Or "They meet" means that they meet someone or meeting with each other

Comment: If an "object"t is specified *(The universe expands **my ability to appreciate God**)*, it's a **transitive** usage. If there's no object, it's an ***intransitive*** usage, which will normally have a significantly different meaning. When Descartes said ***I think*** (with no object), he meant ***I experience / cause thoughts in my head** (not about anything specific)*. Note that in principle I could say ***I love*** to mean *I experience feelings of love [for persons unspecified]* - it just wouldn't be a very likely thing to say, compared to ***I love you*** or "reflexive" ***I love myself***

Comment: I find it almost impossible to imagine a context where you might use truly intransitive ***They meet*** with no stated or implied "object" (usually, the unstated but implied object would be ***each other***). The sentence ***He meets*** is syntactically valid, and in principle *could* be used to mean ***Meeting** [unspecified people] is what he does*, and just maybe you could contrive a context where someone could validly say that (for example, about a hotel worker whose job is to ***meet and greet*** new guests as they arrive). But that would be very unusual.

Comment: Thank you , you have clarified a lot , help me please with one more sentence, " River flows " depending on is the word "flow" a verb or a noun in this sentence means different things, how to differentiate what word type is used? I have problems with such structures when a word can be simultaneously a verb and a noun , one more ambiguity I have a problem with

Comment: it is so confusing especially when such a word is used in plural  "attacks , flows, jokes" and so on and sometimes I dont understand  it means a plural noun or  a third-person singular verb

Comment: An "intransitive" usage like *The river Thames flows* would be extremely unlikely in English in that "bare" form, but it would be fine in something like *The river Thames flows from Gloucestershire all the way to London*. But you'd rarely see the plural *noun* form ***flows*** anyway (there are different ***traffic flows*** in London and Paris, but we wouldn't usually talk about them like that). But you'll just have to get used to the fact that in English we add an /s/ after 3rd-person singular ***verbs*** such as *She **likes** candy* as well as after ***nouns*** (more than one verb or noun).